# spring boot application.yml properties change at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot application, I am able to bind properties from application.yml to the bean fields using @ConfigurationProperties annotation.

Is it possible to update these properties in application.yml at runtime and get them reflected in the bean? If yes. How to do this?

In the past, I've gotten this working using [`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Spring Cloud Config`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config) does that and more. In particular, check [the sample application](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config#sample-application).