# Spring boot - how to modify config properties from an external application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and it has an application.yml file that contains a bunch of properties. I am writing a separate test harness for this application and using that application I would like to modify some properties after the main application starts up. I am thinking that I need to add a new REST endpoint that will implement the PUT method and will change the properties. Using that PUT method I should be able to change any property that is defined in the application.yml file. Is that the correct approach. Is there a sample application that I can take a look at.

Comment: Why you need to modify some properties **after the application starts up** and not on the application startup it self?

Comment: The application is installed using a tool like chef which puts proper values in the application.yml file. Later I want to test this app so that this app sends messages to a mock http server instead of a real http server so that I can verify there responses.

Comment: Why not boot a separate instances just for tests configured properly on startup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot application.yml properties change at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31769462/spring-boot-application-yml-properties-change-at-runtime)

Comment: @YannicKlem I think that question addresses how to manually change the application.yml and refresh the properties to get the changed value. My question is regarding how to change values through an API.